# How to get a list of members out of an IBM i file?

Tags: c++, data-structures, ibm-midrange

New to using IBM i here, and haven't been able to find the solution to this problem in the Knowledge Base.

I have a library. Inside that library I have a file. Inside that file I have several members. Every member is a .c file.

What I want to do is write a .cpp that looks inside that file at the members, get each member's name, and then run CL stuff with the member.

Using qp0z1170.h I am confident I know how to run the CL commands, but I can not seem to figure out how to iterate through the list of members and get their names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qlirlibd.htm?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Actually, this is a pretty decent question, given the [tag:ibm-midrange] tag.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a DSPFD to get the member list to an outfile...

`DSPFD FILE(LIB/FILE) TYPE(*MBRLIST) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(LIB/TARGET)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're dealing with a source physical file (PF-SRC)...

Luckily, a PF-SRC is still a database table..

Just use the [List Database File Members (QUSLMBR) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/quslmbr.htm)

Note that it returns data via a user space...so you're going to need to use the *USRSPC API's to process the data.

[Create User Space (QUSCRTUS) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/quscrtus.htm)
[Change User Space Attributes (QUSCUSAT) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/quscusat.htm)
[Retrieve Pointer to User Space (QUSPTRUS) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qusptrus.htm)
[Delete User Space (QUSDLTUS) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qusdltus.htm)

You can find include files for the IBM API's in the H file in the QSYSINC library.

I'd post some code, but I've only ever used the APIs from RPG.